# Location API works, but neither Google Maps, not Here maps can not find location

Tags: geolocation

I used Holux M-241 as GPS receiver.
On Windows 8.1 I installed GPSDirect drivers, and now can see my location on PC.
I tested  that Location API can access to gps data (I used [this Mozilla Developer Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) to test)
However, no browser-based map application can not find my position. Why?

Comment: Drivers for the M-241 GPS & Windows 8 are here http://www.holux.com/JCore/en/support/downloadCenter.jsp